# I have a field in a table with IDs seperated by the | symbol

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table with a userid and licensed_state.
Data Looks like:

```
userid       Licensed_state
1             |10|11|51|56|73|
```

The values within the | | are ids for states in another table TBLLicensedStates (id, stateName).
Data Looks Like:

```
id           StateName
10           AZ
11           CA
51           NV
56           OR
73           WA
```

I want to create a view the has userid and a licensed state list. Like below.

```
userid      Licensed States
1           AZ, CA, NV, OR, WA
```

I just can not figure out how to do this in a create view statement.
Any suggestions?

This is an inherited problem.  I can not remodel the database.  I have to work with what is there.
We are running SQLServer 2000.

Comment: Any time you have a character-delimited field in a relational database, you're probably modeling your data incorrectly.

Comment: Start by putting your first table in [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: database is SQLServer 2000.

Comment: Agree with @David - if you're going to hold on to old tech like SQL Server 2000 (and even if you're not), you should stop storing data this way and store it correctly...

Comment: I agree.  Not a good way to store/model data.  I agree should upgrade the database.    Is there anyone that can help me with the SQL?